# Is it possible to share USB port hooked by libusb-win32 among several applications?

Tags: windows, libusb

To make my program could communicate with Nokia phone I have setup libusb-win32 library. But after I have this library installed any standard Nokia soft like PC Suite refuses not only to communicate but even to detect my phone! The phone is still available only to my program through libusb-win32 now. Removal of the libusb0.sys driver helps and phone becomes again accessible through Nokia PC Suite, but then it is no more visible to my app via libusb-win32 library. Whether it is somehow possible to get the phone accessible as through libusb-win32 for my application as for standard Nokia phone programs (Nokia PC Suite, NSU, NSS, etc.)?

I run Windows 7 Enterprise and libusb-win32 1.2.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Answer to myself. Yes, it is possible. The driver libusb-win32 should be installed in the filter drive option, not in the device file option.